# Naming the functions for Shaping the data for UI

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

#### Context

I work as a frontend developer, our main stack is Graphql & React that's relevant for this question.

The data I'm requesting can be quite complex and very often combined with several resolvers.

### This is what I tried

- At first, I tried to work with such raw data, but UI was suffering in complexity.
- My solution to simplify render functions I started to write pure convert/normalize/optimize functions
- Purpose of such a function is to take one or multiple data inputs and return a nice(if possible flat) simple structure, essentially I'm shaping the data in a way that can simply be used with any component-based UI library.

### This is My Problem

I don't know how to call those functions, I sometimes call them normalized, sometimes optimize sometimes converters.

Do you maybe know what is 'official' name for such functions?

Comment: I'm not sure that questions asking us to suggest names are a good fit here.  That sounds pretty subjective and a matter of opinion.  This site is for technical questions about computer science.  Any community votes/opinions?

Comment: (Generally name "things" for what they are useful for. *converter* is almost as unspecific as *procedure*, *optimise* & *normalise* no better without an objective function. By contrast, *flatten* was a clue.)

Comment: It's not that I'm asking for name suggestions, I'm trying to understand the category of what I'm doing there, so I would then name it appropriately and be more precise in thinking about it.

@greybeard, thank you for your input. I typically try to express my intent with naming combining action+nount, optimize posts, convertPosts, but again I do understand naming is not clear enough, hance my doubts.